# Style element based on "inner" block modifier

Tags: css, bem

Is it OK to style a block from "outside" depending on an "inner modifier"?
Here's an example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="Header">
    <div class="Button Header__button">
        Seperate Block with optional modifier Button--expanded
    </div>
</div>
```

**button.css**

```
.Button--expanded {
    height: 100%; /* Default height of expanded buttons */
}
```

**header.css**

```
/* Expanded buttons within header have a different height */

/* Approach 1*/
.Header__button.Button--expanded {
    height: 32px;
}

/* Approach 2*/
.Header__button--expanded {
    height: 32px;
}
```

The `Button--expanded` class is dynamically added by some modular JS which only knows the `Button` control/block itself. Therefore `Approach 1` works "out of the box" whilst `Approach 2` would need some extra JS to somehow bubble the `expanded` state up to the `Header` control to set the explicit modifier class `Header__button--expanded` to the `Header__button` element...

I know that there's no absolute right or wrong when it comes to such decisions but I'd really appreciate if someone could point out the pros & cons of each approach.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to style.

Is '--expanded' modifier are common for all Buttons? Or only for Header__button?

If you want to add modifier only for header, use approach 2.

If you want to have more global buttons modifier, use approach 1.